# Screen rotation on ThinkBook 14s Yoga Gen2

Tags: lenovo, tablet, 22.10, display-rotation

I just bought a ThinkBook 14s Yoga Gen2 for my mother for Christmas. Everything I tested works great out of the box. Plasma seems to be missing a virtual keyboard / I had problems with maliit, but with GNOME, everything but one thing seems fine:

Screen rotation.

It is not locked:

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock
false
```

iio-sensor-proxy does report the correct orientation via

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.SensorProxy --object-path /net/hadess/SensorProxy
```

so it is not a driver/hardware issue.

However, the screen does not rotate. Any ideas, anyone?

In the worst case, I'll have to poll the two commands above and write a script myself (feels free to suggest a command to rotate screen in the comments :) ), but it looks like it SHOULD work without coding ...

Comment: Log out and set the session to XServer, not wayland. Then report back.

Comment: Works. Did not know Wayland is standard now. Want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that wayland is not yet capable to react to those inputs. Try to use the XServer.

Log out, change your session to XServer (little cog icon lower right side) and try again.

Comment: You are correct. Here is the open bug report: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1686
Third party workarounds are mentioned, but I'll stick to Xorg for now.

Answer (score 0):

This GNOME extension enables auto screen rotation on Wayland:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5389/screen-rotate/